# NullPointerException when Applying a TypeFace

Tags: android, casting, android-typeface

```
package com.example.kym;  
import android.content.SharedPreferences;  
import android.graphics.Typeface;  
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;  
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;  
import android.widget.ImageView;  
import android.widget.TextView;  
public class Accumulation extends ActionBarActivity  
{  
    TextView tv1,tv2;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc1);  
        Typeface font=null;  
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc2);  
        try  
        {  
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Devanagari.ttf");  
            getData= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());  
            String s=getData.getString("lang", "E");  
            if(s.contentEquals("E"))  
                setContentView(R.layout.accumulation);  
            else if(s.contentEquals("H"))  
            {  
                setContentView(R.layout.accumulationh);  
                tv1.setTypeface(font);  
                tv1.setText("कर दिया");  
            }  
            else if(s.contentEquals("B"))  
            {  
                setContentView(R.layout.accumulationb);  
            }  
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Accumulation Distribution");  
            Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue);  
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);  
        }  
        catch(NullPointerException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}  




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    >
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accimg1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/acc1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/acc2"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is there a `ClassCastException`?

I am trying to use use a custom `TypeFace` on textView1 but its giving the same error everytime.
TextView1 is empty & i want to use a typeface to implement a different language. But everytime it is showing blank even when I applied tv1.setText.

Comment: asked so many times here ... findViewById returns null ... why? google for it

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `findViewById()` until after you've inflated the containing view by calling `setContentView()` on it or by inflating it manually.